# Installing updates

Tags: upgrade

We just installed the abuntu disc 9.04 and are wanting to update. Is there a place you can buy discs to do this or should it be done online. We are new to this and a little bit confused about what to do. Also, are all updates neccesary or can one choose what they want?  Not sure where to go from 9.04  Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to run such an outdated release when there are better current *buntu releases available including lightweight versions designed to give better performance on old hardware?

Answer (score 0):

9.04 has reached end of life so you can not even get security updates for it or any other kind of update.

I suggest you install 12.04LTS for a production machine but if you want the latest features install 13.04.

Here is the link to download ubuntu.
[Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to buy anything, just open Software Updater from the dash and install the updates. If you mean to upgrade, then:
[here](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-1004-1010-1104-to-ubuntu-1110-oneiric-ocelot-desktop-a-server/)

Comment: The link you provide does not relate to Ubuntu 9.04 (an unsupported release). In Ubuntu 9.04 there's no "Software Updater", more like Update Manager (?).